# Metro Bundler local host:8081 not connecting to Android Emulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, react-redux

I have downloaded zip fil from github, did npm install, and run react-native start android.

I receiver the following:

Now when i open the browser it say

[image]

My android emulator is opened but not connected. No error messages.
[image]

Any help how to run the project. The project is in github:
https://github.com/itzpradip/react-navigation-v5-mix.

Thanks
sal

Comment: check adb devices

Comment: thanks anthony , but i could not locate adb.exe

Comment: just added path to adb.exe to the enironment variables. still same issue

Comment: u did fine ? when u use adb devices it show ur devices

Comment: yes i found it. but that didnt resolve. i had another project that i saved. that worked just fine and connected with emulator.since i m new, , and this is my first time importing github project. but i have seen this issue remain unresolved in various forums.

Answer (score 4):

I had the very same issue. Adding this to the android manifest did the trick:

```
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
...
</application>
```

references:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15388
- [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: This is no one talking about.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't install this app on your device , you must use

> react-native run android

to install app , then go for next try you can use start and open app manually

Comment: i dont think that is required. if i have project folder, i need to run npm install, to add all dependencies

Comment: npm install , add all your project dependencies in nodemodule folder , you need react-native run android for install app on device

Comment: did you mean, that i have project folder inside the filer where there is node module folder?

Comment: also i have android studio in my desktop, i m not using external device.

Comment: u can open android folder in android studio and build your project in emulator , after install successfully app you can run your project with __react-native start__

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the app on your emulator by running

```
npm run android
```

or

```
npx react-native run android
```

then start your mentor server by

```
npm start
```